Implement commands in a content-editable textarea in React/Javascript?
Thinking of emulating off of the content areas such as Notion or Obsidian, I'm attempting to design a page content component that allows for commands such as "/bold" that makes the following text bold, as well as deleting the command meaning "hello /bold" would be "hello " once the command is submitted ('enter' or so).
Thus far, the challenge has been making use of a contenteditable  as  is not editable, however to do this means I have to PATCH and GET the content everytime it changes, currently utilizing through an onInput={handleInput} type of trigger.
The primary problem derives from how to edit the content when manually deleting text such as the command content. Currently, I attempt to PATCH everytime I delete a command (triggered by submitting a valid command), however this means I need to either reload the page or GET the content again which resets the cursor position alongside delays.
<div
    name="page-content" 
    id="page-content" 
    contenteditable="true"
    className="page-content-container"
    onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
    onInput={handleInput}
/>

const updateContent = async (newContent) => {
        setContent(newContent);
    
        try {
          const response = await fetch(`/pages/${id}`, {
            method: 'PATCH',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            body: JSON.stringify({ content: newContent }),
          });
    
          if (!response.ok) {
            const errorData = await response.json();
            console.error('Failed to update content:', errorData);
          }
        } catch (err) {
          console.error('Error:', err);
        }
    }

if (foundCommand) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Remove the command and '/' before it from the content
    const currentContent = document.getElementById('page-content').innerHTML;
    const commandStart = currentContent.lastIndexOf('/') + 1;
    const newContent = currentContent.substring(0, commandStart - 1); // Remove command including the slash

    // Update content of the div
    document.getElementById('page-content').innerHTML = newContent;

    // Update the content
    updateContent(newContent);
    foundCommand.execute();
}

I'm sure there are better ways to do this, however I'm tackling everything for the first time and intend to redo the whole thing later on when I realize how inefficiently I designed it. Any courses on notetaking software and the like would be fantastic. Thanks!
